# How can I get gdb's print to respect newlines?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I have used `set print elements 0` to ensure it does not truncate the output, but still it shows `\n` instead of actually respecting the newline.

Comment: `set print elements` just controls how much of the string it displays, not the format that it uses.

Comment: Yes I'm aware. I needed to use `set print elements` to print the entire output, and wanted to include that in my question in case it somehow affected the newline handling

Comment: As far as I can tell from the manual, there's no print option related to newlines.

Comment: What is the data type of the argument you're giving to `print`? If it's a C string (NUL-terminated sequence of characters), try `printf`. If it's a structure that contains strings and other stuff, you may need to write a script.

Comment: It is i std::string

Comment: Try `(gdb) printf "%s\n", (char *)TheStdStringExpression` . It will print the string without converting any non-printable characters into escape sequences. But it will stop at the first NUL in the string.